# Closure Compiler doesn't minify functions inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have this piece of code, compiled from TypeScript to JavaScript, that I want to minify with the Google Closure Compiler:

```
var api;
(function (api) {
    function connect() {
        console.log("connected!");
    }
    api.connect = connect;
})(api || (api = {}));
api.connect();
```

This is compiled to:

```
var a;
(function(b) {
  b.connect = function() {
    console.log("connected!");
  };
})(a || (a = {}));
a.connect();
```

As you can see, the name of the `connect` function inside the anonymous function is not renamed to something like `a` or `b`.

How can I tell the compiler to minify the name of the `connect` function?

EDIT:

Seems like this is because `connect` is a reserved word. When I replace `connect` with `connectt`, the problem is gone.

```
var api;
(function (api) {
    function connectt() {
        console.log("connected!");
    }
    api.connectt = connectt;
})(api || (api = {}));
api.connectt();
```

Compiles to:

```
var a;
(function(b) {
  b.a = function() {
    console.log("connected!");
  };
})(a || (a = {}));
a.a();
```

Thanks to @A. Andres !

Comment: Looking through the API documentation I couldn't see an option regarding what you want... but you can always find a tool which obfuscates the code after the Goggle Closure Compiler has run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some properties won't be renamed because they are declared in an [externs file](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?csw=1#externs). If the compiler can't decide whether a property is part of an external dependency then it won't be renamed.

In your specific case, I can see that there is a method called `connect` that is part of the Web Audio API in [externs/browser/w3c_audio.js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/6e7b288fdd48dbe4437ab7161b021adee15f2ef0/externs/browser/w3c_audio.js#L243) (`AudioNode.prototype.connect`).

Property renaming is explained in great detail in the [Closure Compiler FAQ](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#some-of-my-properties-are-getting-renamed-but-some-arent-why) and the blog posts mentioned there.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly tell the compiler to rename the `connect` function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are passing your namespace in via an IIFE argument. If you avoid that, you get the results you want.

```
const api = {};
(function () {
  function connect() {
    console.log("connected!");
  }
  api.connect = connect;
})();
api.connect();
```

The compiler doesn't recognize `api` as a type and therefore doesn't have enough information to differentiate the properties from other objects. By avoiding the alias created by the IIFE call and using `const` to tell the compiler that `api` is a namespace, you can get the optimizations you seek.

Comment: I can't avoid passing the namespace in via an IIFE argument, because TypeScript generates this construction.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way for the compiler to rename those properties. It does not have enough information to indicate that such renaming is safe.